# How to add external class using psr-0 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, psr-0

I am adding my own class in laravel for Amaezone S3 service.
Here is my composer file

```
"psr-0":{"App\\": "app/src/"}
```

I have created directory in `app/src/App`

and put all the lib of amezone into this directory

Now create a class `Amezones3.php` and put some my own code, in this class I want to add include a class which is amezoneS3 service class.

In class `Amezones3.php` my construct function are below

```
<?php namespace App;

class Amezones3 extends \BaseController{


/**
 *  Decalare Bucket Variable for S3
 *  default public
 */
public $bucketName;



/**
 *  Decalare Filename Variable for S3,this file name goes on the S3 server
 *  default public
 */
public $fileName;

/**
 *  Decalare Amezone S3 Object
 *  default public
 */
public $amazones3Obj;


/**
 *  Construct Fucntion for creating object of the AmezoneS3 Object
 *  Assign the created Object to @amazones3Obj variable
 *  @include the 'sdk.class.php' which is amezone PHP SDK for Serveice S3
 *  Created Object assign to variable @amazones3Obj
 */
public function __construct(){
    require_once __DIR__.'/sdk.class.php';
    $s3 = new AmazonS3();
    $this->amazones3Obj=$s3;
    pr($this->amazones3Obj);

}

/**
 * Create Bucket from the server 
 * @pass String 'Bucket Name'
 * @return true on successfull
 * @return false on fail
 */
public function create_bucket($bucket)
{
    $s3 = $this->amazones3Obj;
    $response = $s3->create_bucket($bucket,AmazonS3::REGION_US_STANDARD);
    if($response->isOK()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
}


/**
 * Delete Bucket from the server 
 * @pass String 'Bucket Name'
 * @return true on successfull
 * @return false on fail
 */
public function delete_bucket($bucket)
{
    $s3 = $this->amazones3Obj;
    $deletebukets = $s3->delete_bucket($bucket,"true");
    if($deletebukets){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;   
    }
}


/**
 *  Upload File on the bucket
 *  @pass string 'Bucket'
 *  @pass string 'File Name'
 *  @bucketName string Required The name of the bucket to use.
 *  @return string URL of the image of filename
 *  Fore More Details:: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/create_object
 * 
 */
function put_file_upload_to_server($bucketName,$fileName){ 
    $s3 = $this->amazones3Obj;
    $this->bucketName=$bucketName;
    $this->fileName=$fileName;
    $fileNameArray=explode('.',$fileName);
    $extName=end($fileNameArray);
    $newFileName='img'.md5(time()).'.'.$extName;
    $this->fileName=$newFileName;
    //$newFileName=$fileName;
    $mimeType=$this->get_mime_type($extName);
    if($mimeType!='No Mime Type found'){
    $response = $s3->create_object($bucketName,$newFileName, 
            array('fileUpload' => $fileName,
            'contentType' =>$mimeType, 
            //'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
            //'storage' => AmazonS3::STORAGE_REDUCED,
            'grants' => array(
                array( 'id' => AmazonS3::USERS_AUTH,'permission' => AmazonS3::GRANT_FULL_CONTROL)
            )
            ));
        if($this->set_object_acl()){
            return $response->header['_info']['url'];
        }else{
                echo "Failed To Set ACl";
        }
    }else{
        echo "No Valid Mime type Found";
    }
}


/**
 *  @acl string Optional The ACL settings for the specified object. 
 *  Accepts any of the following constants: 
 *  [Allowed values: AmazonS3::ACL_PRIVATE, AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC, AmazonS3::ACL_OPEN, AmazonS3::ACL_AUTH_READ, 
 *  AmazonS3::ACL_OWNER_READ, AmazonS3::ACL_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL]. 
 *  Alternatively, an array of associative arrays. Each associative array contains an id and a permission key. 
 *  The default value is ACL_PRIVATE.
 */ 
private function set_object_acl(){
    $bucketName=$this->bucketName;
    $fileName=$this->fileName;
    $response=$this->amazones3Obj->set_object_acl($bucketName,$fileName, AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC);
    if($response->isOK()){
            return true;
    }else{
            return false;
    }

}   


/**
 * Get All the types of Mime Type for file 
 */
public function get_mime_type($extName){
$mime_types_map = array(
'3dm' => 'x-world/x-3dmf','3dmf' => 'x-world/x-3dmf','a' => 'application/octet-stream','aab' => 'application/x-authorware-bin',
'aam' => 'application/x-authorware-map', 'aas' => 'application/x-authorware-seg', 'abc' => 'text/vnd.abc', 'acgi' => 'text/html',
'afl' => 'video/animaflex', 'ai' => 'application/postscript', 'aif' => 'audio/aiff', 'aif' => 'audio/x-aiff',
'aifc' => 'audio/aiff', 'aifc' => 'audio/x-aiff', 'aiff' => 'audio/aiff', 'aiff' => 'audio/x-aiff',
'aim' => 'application/x-aim', 'aip' => 'text/x-audiosoft-intra', 'ani' => 'application/x-navi-animation', 'aos' => 'application/x-nokia-9000-communicator-add-on-software',
'aps' => 'application/mime', 'arc' => 'application/octet-stream', 'arj' => 'application/arj', 'arj' => 'application/octet-stream',
'art' => 'image/x-jg', 'asf' => 'video/x-ms-asf', 'asm' => 'text/x-asm', 'asp' => 'text/asp',
'asx' => 'application/x-mplayer2', 'asx' => 'video/x-ms-asf', 'asx' => 'video/x-ms-asf-plugin', 'au' => 'audio/basic',
'au' => 'audio/x-au', 'avi' => 'application/x-troff-msvideo', 'avi' => 'video/avi', 'avi' => 'video/msvideo',
'avi' => 'video/x-msvideo', 'avs' => 'video/avs-video', 'bcpio' => 'application/x-bcpio', 'bin' => 'application/mac-binary',
'bin' => 'application/macbinary', 'bin' => 'application/octet-stream', 'bin' => 'application/x-binary', 'bin' => 'application/x-macbinary',
'bm' => 'image/bmp', 'bmp' => 'image/bmp', 'bmp' => 'image/x-windows-bmp', 'boo' => 'application/book',
'book' => 'application/book', 'boz' => 'application/x-bzip2', 'bsh' => 'application/x-bsh', 'bz' => 'application/x-bzip',
'bz2' => 'application/x-bzip2', 'c' => 'text/plain', 'c' => 'text/x-c', 'c++' => 'text/plain',
'cat' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat', 'cc' => 'text/plain', 'cc' => 'text/x-c', 'ccad' => 'application/clariscad',
'cco' => 'application/x-cocoa', 'cdf' => 'application/cdf', 'cdf' => 'application/x-cdf', 'cdf' => 'application/x-netcdf',
'cer' => 'application/pkix-cert', 'cer' => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert', 'cha' => 'application/x-chat', 'chat' => 'application/x-chat',
'class' => 'application/java', 'class' => 'application/java-byte-code', 'class' => 'application/x-java-class', 'com' => 'application/octet-stream',
'com' => 'text/plain', 'conf' => 'text/plain', 'cpio' => 'application/x-cpio', 'cpp' => 'text/x-c',
'cpt' => 'application/mac-compactpro', 'cpt' => 'application/x-compactpro', 'cpt' => 'application/x-cpt', 'crl' => 'application/pkcs-crl',
'crl' => 'application/pkix-crl', 'crt' => 'application/pkix-cert', 'crt' => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert', 'crt' => 'application/x-x509-user-cert',
'csh' => 'application/x-csh', 'csh' => 'text/x-script.csh', 'css' => 'application/x-pointplus', 'css' => 'text/css',
'cxx' => 'text/plain', 'dcr' => 'application/x-director', 'deepv' => 'application/x-deepv', 'def' => 'text/plain',
'der' => 'application/x-x509-ca-cert', 'dif' => 'video/x-dv', 'dir' => 'application/x-director', 'dl' => 'video/dl',
'dl' => 'video/x-dl', 'doc' => 'application/msword', 'dot' => 'application/msword', 'dp' => 'application/commonground',
'drw' => 'application/drafting', 'dump' => 'application/octet-stream', 'dv' => 'video/x-dv', 'dvi' => 'application/x-dvi',
'dwf' => 'drawing/x-dwf', 'dwf' => 'model/vnd.dwf', 'dwg' => 'application/acad', 'dwg' => 'image/vnd.dwg',
'dwg' => 'image/x-dwg', 'dxf' => 'application/dxf', 'dxf' => 'image/vnd.dwg', 'dxf' => 'image/x-dwg',
'dxr' => 'application/x-director', 'el' => 'text/x-script.elisp', 'elc' => 'application/x-bytecode.elisp', 'elc' => 'application/x-elc',
'env' => 'application/x-envoy', 'eps' => 'application/postscript', 'es' => 'application/x-esrehber', 'etx' => 'text/x-setext',
'evy' => 'application/envoy', 'evy' => 'application/x-envoy', 'exe' => 'application/octet-stream', 'f' => 'text/plain',
'f' => 'text/x-fortran', 'f77' => 'text/x-fortran', 'f90' => 'text/plain', 'f90' => 'text/x-fortran',
'fdf' => 'application/vnd.fdf', 'fif' => 'application/fractals', 'fif' => 'image/fif', 'fli' => 'video/fli',
'fli' => 'video/x-fli', 'flo' => 'image/florian', 'flx' => 'text/vnd.fmi.flexstor', 'fmf' => 'video/x-atomic3d-feature',
'for' => 'text/plain', 'for' => 'text/x-fortran', 'fpx' => 'image/vnd.fpx', 'fpx' => 'image/vnd.net-fpx',
'frl' => 'application/freeloader', 'funk' => 'audio/make', 'g' => 'text/plain', 'g3' => 'image/g3fax',
'gif' => 'image/gif', 'gl' => 'video/gl', 'gl' => 'video/x-gl', 'gsd' => 'audio/x-gsm',
'gsm' => 'audio/x-gsm', 'gsp' => 'application/x-gsp', 'gss' => 'application/x-gss', 'gtar' => 'application/x-gtar',
'gz' => 'application/x-compressed', 'gz' => 'application/x-gzip', 'gzip' => 'application/x-gzip', 'gzip' => 'multipart/x-gzip',
'h' => 'text/plain', 'h' => 'text/x-h', 'hdf' => 'application/x-hdf', 'help' => 'application/x-helpfile',
'hgl' => 'application/vnd.hp-hpgl', 'hh' => 'text/plain', 'hh' => 'text/x-h', 'hlb' => 'text/x-script',
'hlp' => 'application/hlp', 'hlp' => 'application/x-helpfile', 'hlp' => 'application/x-winhelp', 'hpg' => 'application/vnd.hp-hpgl',
'hpgl' => 'application/vnd.hp-hpgl', 'hqx' => 'application/binhex', 'hqx' => 'application/binhex4', 'hqx' => 'application/mac-binhex',
'hqx' => 'application/mac-binhex40', 'hqx' => 'application/x-binhex40', 'hqx' => 'application/x-mac-binhex40', 'hta' => 'application/hta',
'htc' => 'text/x-component', 'htm' => 'text/html', 'html' => 'text/html', 'htmls' => 'text/html',
'htt' => 'text/webviewhtml', 'htx' => 'text/html', 'ice' => 'x-conference/x-cooltalk', 'ico' => 'image/x-icon',
'idc' => 'text/plain', 'ief' => 'image/ief', 'iefs' => 'image/ief', 'iges' => 'application/iges',
'iges' => 'model/iges', 'igs' => 'application/iges', 'igs' => 'model/iges', 'ima' => 'application/x-ima',
'imap' => 'application/x-httpd-imap', 'inf' => 'application/inf', 'ins' => 'application/x-internett-signup', 'ip' => 'application/x-ip2',
'isu' => 'video/x-isvideo', 'it' => 'audio/it', 'iv' => 'application/x-inventor', 'ivr' => 'i-world/i-vrml',
'ivy' => 'application/x-livescreen', 'jam' => 'audio/x-jam', 'jav' => 'text/plain', 'jav' => 'text/x-java-source',
'java' => 'text/plain', 'java' => 'text/x-java-source', 'jcm' => 'application/x-java-commerce', 'jfif' => 'image/jpeg',
'jfif' => 'image/pjpeg', 'jfif-tbnl' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpe' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpe' => 'image/pjpeg',
'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpeg' => 'image/pjpeg', 'jpg' => 'image/jpeg', 'jpg' => 'image/pjpeg',
'jps' => 'image/x-jps', 'js' => 'application/x-javascript', 'jut' => 'image/jutvision', 'kar' => 'audio/midi',
'kar' => 'music/x-karaoke', 'ksh' => 'application/x-ksh', 'ksh' => 'text/x-script.ksh', 'la' => 'audio/nspaudio',
'la' => 'audio/x-nspaudio', 'lam' => 'audio/x-liveaudio', 'latex' => 'application/x-latex', 'lha' => 'application/lha',
'lha' => 'application/octet-stream', 'lha' => 'application/x-lha', 'lhx' => 'application/octet-stream', 'list' => 'text/plain',
'lma' => 'audio/nspaudio', 'lma' => 'audio/x-nspaudio', 'log' => 'text/plain', 'lsp' => 'application/x-lisp',
'lsp' => 'text/x-script.lisp', 'lst' => 'text/plain', 'lsx' => 'text/x-la-asf', 'ltx' => 'application/x-latex',
'lzh' => 'application/octet-stream', 'lzh' => 'application/x-lzh', 'lzx' => 'application/lzx', 'lzx' => 'application/octet-stream',
'lzx' => 'application/x-lzx', 'm' => 'text/plain', 'm' => 'text/x-m', 'm1v' => 'video/mpeg',
'm2a' => 'audio/mpeg', 'm2v' => 'video/mpeg', 'm3u' => 'audio/x-mpequrl', 'man' => 'application/x-troff-man',
'map' => 'application/x-navimap', 'mar' => 'text/plain', 'mbd' => 'application/mbedlet', 'mc$' => 'application/x-magic-cap-package-1.0',
'mcd' => 'application/mcad', 'mcd' => 'application/x-mathcad', 'mcf' => 'image/vasa', 'mcf' => 'text/mcf',
'mcp' => 'application/netmc', 'me' => 'application/x-troff-me', 'mht' => 'message/rfc822', 'mhtml' => 'message/rfc822',
'mid' => 'application/x-midi', 'mid' => 'audio/midi', 'mid' => 'audio/x-mid', 'mid' => 'audio/x-midi',
'mid' => 'music/crescendo', 'mid' => 'x-music/x-midi', 'midi' => 'application/x-midi', 'midi' => 'audio/midi',
'midi' => 'audio/x-mid', 'midi' => 'audio/x-midi', 'midi' => 'music/crescendo', 'midi' => 'x-music/x-midi',
'mif' => 'application/x-frame', 'mif' => 'application/x-mif', 'mime' => 'message/rfc822', 'mime' => 'www/mime',
'mjf' => 'audio/x-vnd.audioexplosion.mjuicemediafile', 'mjpg' => 'video/x-motion-jpeg', 'mm' => 'application/base64', 'mm' => 'application/x-meme',
'mme' => 'application/base64', 'mod' => 'audio/mod', 'mod' => 'audio/x-mod', 'moov' => 'video/quicktime',
'mov' => 'video/quicktime', 'movie' => 'video/x-sgi-movie', 'mp2' => 'audio/mpeg', 'mp2' => 'audio/x-mpeg',
'mp2' => 'video/mpeg', 'mp2' => 'video/x-mpeg', 'mp2' => 'video/x-mpeq2a', 'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg3',
'mp3' => 'audio/x-mpeg-3', 'mp3' => 'video/mpeg', 'mp3' => 'video/x-mpeg', 'mpa' => 'audio/mpeg',
'mpa' => 'video/mpeg', 'mpc' => 'application/x-project', 'mpe' => 'video/mpeg', 'mpeg' => 'video/mpeg',
'mpg' => 'audio/mpeg', 'mpg' => 'video/mpeg', 'mpga' => 'audio/mpeg', 'mpp' => 'application/vnd.ms-project',
'mpt' => 'application/x-project', 'mpv' => 'application/x-project', 'mpx' => 'application/x-project', 'mrc' => 'application/marc',
'ms' => 'application/x-troff-ms', 'mv' => 'video/x-sgi-movie', 'my' => 'audio/make', 'mzz' => 'application/x-vnd.audioexplosion.mzz',
'nap' => 'image/naplps', 'naplps' => 'image/naplps', 'nc' => 'application/x-netcdf', 'ncm' => 'application/vnd.nokia.configuration-message',
'nif' => 'image/x-niff', 'niff' => 'image/x-niff', 'nix' => 'application/x-mix-transfer', 'nsc' => 'application/x-conference',
'nvd' => 'application/x-navidoc', 'o' => 'application/octet-stream', 'oda' => 'application/oda', 'omc' => 'application/x-omc',
'omcd' => 'application/x-omcdatamaker', 'omcr' => 'application/x-omcregerator', 'p' => 'text/x-pascal', 'p10' => 'application/pkcs10',
'p10' => 'application/x-pkcs10', 'p12' => 'application/pkcs-12', 'p12' => 'application/x-pkcs12', 'p7a' => 'application/x-pkcs7-signature',
'p7c' => 'application/pkcs7-mime', 'p7c' => 'application/x-pkcs7-mime', 'p7m' => 'application/pkcs7-mime', 'p7m' => 'application/x-pkcs7-mime',
'p7r' => 'application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp', 'p7s' => 'application/pkcs7-signature', 'part' => 'application/pro_eng', 'pas' => 'text/pascal',
'pbm' => 'image/x-portable-bitmap', 'pcl' => 'application/vnd.hp-pcl', 'pcl' => 'application/x-pcl', 'pct' => 'image/x-pict',
'pcx' => 'image/x-pcx', 'pdb' => 'chemical/x-pdb', 'pdf' => 'application/pdf', 'pfunk' => 'audio/make',
'pfunk' => 'audio/make.my.funk', 'pgm' => 'image/x-portable-graymap', 'pgm' => 'image/x-portable-greymap', 'pic' => 'image/pict',
'pict' => 'image/pict', 'pkg' => 'application/x-newton-compatible-pkg', 'pko' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.pko', 'pl' => 'text/plain',
'pl' => 'text/x-script.perl', 'plx' => 'application/x-pixclscript', 'pm' => 'image/x-xpixmap', 'pm' => 'text/x-script.perl-module',
'pm4' => 'application/x-pagemaker', 'pm5' => 'application/x-pagemaker', 'png' => 'image/png', 'pnm' => 'application/x-portable-anymap',
'pnm' => 'image/x-portable-anymap', 'pot' => 'application/mspowerpoint', 'pot' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'pov' => 'model/x-pov',
'ppa' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'ppm' => 'image/x-portable-pixmap', 'pps' => 'application/mspowerpoint', 'pps' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
'ppt' => 'application/mspowerpoint', 'ppt' => 'application/powerpoint', 'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'ppt' => 'application/x-mspowerpoint',
'ppz' => 'application/mspowerpoint', 'pre' => 'application/x-freelance', 'prt' => 'application/pro_eng', 'ps' => 'application/postscript',
'psd' => 'application/octet-stream', 'pvu' => 'paleovu/x-pv', 'pwz' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'py' => 'text/x-script.phyton',
'pyc' => 'applicaiton/x-bytecode.python', 'qcp' => 'audio/vnd.qcelp', 'qd3' => 'x-world/x-3dmf', 'qd3d' => 'x-world/x-3dmf',
'qif' => 'image/x-quicktime', 'qt' => 'video/quicktime', 'qtc' => 'video/x-qtc', 'qti' => 'image/x-quicktime',
'qtif' => 'image/x-quicktime', 'ra' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio', 'ra' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin', 'ra' => 'audio/x-realaudio',
'ram' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio', 'ras' => 'application/x-cmu-raster', 'ras' => 'image/cmu-raster', 'ras' => 'image/x-cmu-raster',
'rast' => 'image/cmu-raster', 'rexx' => 'text/x-script.rexx', 'rf' => 'image/vnd.rn-realflash', 'rgb' => 'image/x-rgb',
'rm' => 'application/vnd.rn-realmedia', 'rm' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio', 'rmi' => 'audio/mid', 'rmm' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
'rmp' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio', 'rmp' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin', 'rng' => 'application/ringing-tones', 'rng' => 'application/vnd.nokia.ringing-tone',
'rnx' => 'application/vnd.rn-realplayer', 'roff' => 'application/x-troff', 'rp' => 'image/vnd.rn-realpix', 'rpm' => 'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin',
'rt' => 'text/richtext', 'rt' => 'text/vnd.rn-realtext', 'rtf' => 'application/rtf', 'rtf' => 'application/x-rtf',
'rtf' => 'text/richtext', 'rtx' => 'application/rtf', 'rtx' => 'text/richtext', 'rv' => 'video/vnd.rn-realvideo',
's' => 'text/x-asm', 's3m' => 'audio/s3m', 'saveme' => 'application/octet-stream', 'sbk' => 'application/x-tbook',
'scm' => 'application/x-lotusscreencam', 'scm' => 'text/x-script.guile', 'scm' => 'text/x-script.scheme', 'scm' => 'video/x-scm',
'sdml' => 'text/plain', 'sdp' => 'application/sdp', 'sdp' => 'application/x-sdp', 'sdr' => 'application/sounder',
'sea' => 'application/sea', 'sea' => 'application/x-sea', 'set' => 'application/set', 'sgm' => 'text/sgml',
'sgm' => 'text/x-sgml', 'sgml' => 'text/sgml', 'sgml' => 'text/x-sgml', 'sh' => 'application/x-bsh',
'sh' => 'application/x-sh', 'sh' => 'application/x-shar', 'sh' => 'text/x-script.sh', 'shar' => 'application/x-bsh',
'shar' => 'application/x-shar', 'shtml' => 'text/html', 'shtml' => 'text/x-server-parsed-html', 'sid' => 'audio/x-psid',
'sit' => 'application/x-sit', 'sit' => 'application/x-stuffit', 'skd' => 'application/x-koan', 'skm' => 'application/x-koan',
'skp' => 'application/x-koan', 'skt' => 'application/x-koan', 'sl' => 'application/x-seelogo', 'smi' => 'application/smil',
'smil' => 'application/smil', 'snd' => 'audio/basic', 'snd' => 'audio/x-adpcm', 'sol' => 'application/solids',
'spc' => 'application/x-pkcs7-certificates', 'spc' => 'text/x-speech', 'spl' => 'application/futuresplash', 'spr' => 'application/x-sprite',
'sprite' => 'application/x-sprite', 'src' => 'application/x-wais-source', 'ssi' => 'text/x-server-parsed-html', 'ssm' => 'application/streamingmedia',
'sst' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.certstore', 'step' => 'application/step', 'stl' => 'application/sla', 'stl' => 'application/vnd.ms-pki.stl',
'stl' => 'application/x-navistyle', 'stp' => 'application/step', 'sv4cpio' => 'application/x-sv4cpio', 'sv4crc' => 'application/x-sv4crc',
'svf' => 'image/vnd.dwg', 'svf' => 'image/x-dwg', 'svr' => 'application/x-world', 'svr' => 'x-world/x-svr',
'swf' => 'application/x-shockwave-flash', 't' => 'application/x-troff', 'talk' => 'text/x-speech', 'tar' => 'application/x-tar',
'tbk' => 'application/toolbook', 'tbk' => 'application/x-tbook', 'tcl' => 'application/x-tcl', 'tcl' => 'text/x-script.tcl',
'tcsh' => 'text/x-script.tcsh', 'tex' => 'application/x-tex', 'texi' => 'application/x-texinfo', 'texinfo' => 'application/x-texinfo',
'text' => 'application/plain', 'text' => 'text/plain', 'tgz' => 'application/gnutar', 'tgz' => 'application/x-compressed',
'tif' => 'image/tiff', 'tif' => 'image/x-tiff', 'tiff' => 'image/tiff', 'tiff' => 'image/x-tiff',
'tr' => 'application/x-troff', 'tsi' => 'audio/tsp-audio', 'tsp' => 'application/dsptype', 'tsp' => 'audio/tsplayer',
'tsv' => 'text/tab-separated-values', 'turbot' => 'image/florian', 'txt' => 'text/plain', 'uil' => 'text/x-uil',
'uni' => 'text/uri-list', 'unis' => 'text/uri-list', 'unv' => 'application/i-deas', 'uri' => 'text/uri-list',
'uris' => 'text/uri-list', 'ustar' => 'application/x-ustar', 'ustar' => 'multipart/x-ustar', 'uu' => 'application/octet-stream',
'uu' => 'text/x-uuencode', 'uue' => 'text/x-uuencode', 'vcd' => 'application/x-cdlink', 'vcs' => 'text/x-vcalendar',
'vda' => 'application/vda', 'vdo' => 'video/vdo', 'vew' => 'application/groupwise', 'viv' => 'video/vivo',
'viv' => 'video/vnd.vivo', 'vivo' => 'video/vivo', 'vivo' => 'video/vnd.vivo', 'vmd' => 'application/vocaltec-media-desc',
'vmf' => 'application/vocaltec-media-file', 'voc' => 'audio/voc', 'voc' => 'audio/x-voc', 'vos' => 'video/vosaic',
'vox' => 'audio/voxware', 'vqe' => 'audio/x-twinvq-plugin', 'vqf' => 'audio/x-twinvq', 'vql' => 'audio/x-twinvq-plugin',
'vrml' => 'application/x-vrml', 'vrml' => 'model/vrml', 'vrml' => 'x-world/x-vrml', 'vrt' => 'x-world/x-vrt',
'vsd' => 'application/x-visio', 'vst' => 'application/x-visio', 'vsw' => 'application/x-visio', 'w60' => 'application/wordperfect6.0',
'w61' => 'application/wordperfect6.1', 'w6w' => 'application/msword', 'wav' => 'audio/wav', 'wav' => 'audio/x-wav',
'wb1' => 'application/x-qpro', 'wbmp' => 'image/vnd.wap.wbmp', 'web' => 'application/vnd.xara', 'wiz' => 'application/msword',
'wk1' => 'application/x-123', 'wmf' => 'windows/metafile', 'wml' => 'text/vnd.wap.wml', 'wmlc' => 'application/vnd.wap.wmlc',
'wmls' => 'text/vnd.wap.wmlscript', 'wmlsc' => 'application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc', 'word' => 'application/msword', 'wp' => 'application/wordperfect',
'wp5' => 'application/wordperfect', 'wp5' => 'application/wordperfect6.0', 'wp6' => 'application/wordperfect', 'wpd' => 'application/wordperfect',
'wpd' => 'application/x-wpwin', 'wq1' => 'application/x-lotus', 'wri' => 'application/mswrite', 'wri' => 'application/x-wri',
'wrl' => 'application/x-world', 'wrl' => 'model/vrml', 'wrl' => 'x-world/x-vrml', 'wrz' => 'model/vrml',
'wrz' => 'x-world/x-vrml', 'wsc' => 'text/scriplet', 'wsrc' => 'application/x-wais-source', 'wtk' => 'application/x-wintalk',
'xbm' => 'image/x-xbitmap', 'xbm' => 'image/x-xbm', 'xbm' => 'image/xbm', 'xdr' => 'video/x-amt-demorun',
'xgz' => 'xgl/drawing', 'xif' => 'image/vnd.xiff', 'xl' => 'application/excel', 'xla' => 'application/excel',
'xla' => 'application/x-excel', 'xla' => 'application/x-msexcel', 'xlb' => 'application/excel', 'xlb' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
'xlb' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlc' => 'application/excel', 'xlc' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'xlc' => 'application/x-excel',
'xld' => 'application/excel', 'xld' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlk' => 'application/excel', 'xlk' => 'application/x-excel',
'xll' => 'application/excel', 'xll' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'xll' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlm' => 'application/excel',
'xlm' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'xlm' => 'application/x-excel', 'xls' => 'application/excel', 'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
'xls' => 'application/x-excel', 'xls' => 'application/x-msexcel', 'xlt' => 'application/excel', 'xlt' => 'application/x-excel',
'xlv' => 'application/excel', 'xlv' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlw' => 'application/excel', 'xlw' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
'xlw' => 'application/x-excel', 'xlw' => 'application/x-msexcel', 'xm' => 'audio/xm', 'xml' => 'application/xml',
'xml' => 'text/xml', 'xmz' => 'xgl/movie', 'xpix' => 'application/x-vnd.ls-xpix', 'xpm' => 'image/x-xpixmap',
'xpm' => 'image/xpm', 'x-png' => 'image/png', 'xsr' => 'video/x-amt-showrun', 'xwd' => 'image/x-xwd',
'xwd' => 'image/x-xwindowdump', 'xyz' => 'chemical/x-pdb', 'z' => 'application/x-compress', 'z' => 'application/x-compressed',
'zip' => 'application/x-compressed', 'zip' => 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'zip' => 'application/zip', 'zip' => 'multipart/x-zip',
'zoo' => 'application/octet-stream', 'zsh' => 'text/x-script.zsh',
);
if($mime_types_map[$extName]){
    return $mime_types_map[$extName];
}else{
    return "No Mime Type found";
}
}
```

}
?>

```
public function __construct(){
    require_once __DIR__.'/sdk.class.php';
    $s3 = new AmazonS3();
    $this->amazones3Obj=$s3;
    pr($this->amazones3Obj);

}
```

But when I run the page that will give error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
"Class 'App\AmazonS3' not found"
```

I am follwing this video which is working fine here

```
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2014/01/autoloading-laravel-application-code-with-psr4
```

Note: every thing working fine, but when I try to inlcude a class into ctructor that will not working.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.
Prads

Answer (score 0):

You need to teach PHP the AmazonS3 namespace:

```
<?php namespace App;

use The\Namespace\Of\Your\Class\AmazonS3; // <---- add a USE clause to do that

class Amezones3 extends \BaseController{


    /**
     *  Decalare Bucket Variable for S3
     *  default public
     */
    public $bucketName;

    ...

}
```

Then you can use it as

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
```

Or you can just do it inline:

```
public function __construct()
{
    require_once __DIR__.'/sdk.class.php';

    $s3 = new The\Namespace\Of\Your\Class\AmazonS3();

    $this->amazones3Obj=$s3;

    pr($this->amazones3Obj);
}
```